# runtime error with mongocxx::options::find

Tags: mongodb

It works fine when I do query without option

```
document condition;
condition << "age" << 22;

auto cursor = collection_.find(condition.view());

for (auto&& doc : cursor)
{
    std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
}
```

but once I use mongocxx::options::find opts

```
document condition;
condition << "age" << 22;

mongocxx::options::find opts{};
opts.limit(1);

auto cursor = collection_.find(condition.view(), opts);

for (auto&& doc : cursor)
{
    std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
}
```

read access permission conflicts error occured
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtWd4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I recompiled mongocxx and built a new project, the error didn't appear. Maybe there is something wrong with my previous environment.

Comment: Have you noticed where the difference is?